# I'm making ASP .NET MVC application, I'm getting this error when running the project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting the following error

[image]

This is my connection string in web.config

```
<!--EmployeeContext connection string-->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\VisualStudioProjects\C# projects\LocalDBApplication\LocalDBApplication\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is clear that you have duplicate connectionStrings section in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly says you have more than one `<conncetionStrings>` section specified. Check your code and remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

It only allowed one `<connectionStrings>` section in config file. Check your `web.config` to remove or merge your defined connections.